# Wrong delete in Navigation Stack in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms, stack

I have a little, simple but crazy problem with Xamarin.Forms and its Navigation Pages system.
I have my App that start like this:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new IntroPage());
```

So, I have my NavigationPage. Now, I do something operation and my Navigation Stack (from top to down) is like this:

```
NewPersonPage (Page where I am now)
------
RolePage
------
RegisterPage
------
DetailsPage
------
HomePage
------
IntroPage
```

Now, I want to do this. 
Delete from this stack: Role, Register and Details Page.
After, going to new DetailsPage for have a situation like this:

```
DetailsPage (new, and where I am now)
------
NewPersonPage
------
HomePage
------
IntroPage
```

To do it, in NewPersonPage I do this:

```
// Remove RolePage
Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
// Remove RegisterPage
Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
// Remove DetailsPage
Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);

// Now create new DetailsPage and go here
await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(stuff));
```

And for now there aren't a problems.
Now, from my new DetailsPage, I want to delete the NewPersonPage from my stack. So I do this:

```
// Remove NewPersonPage 
Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
```

But it doesn't works! Throw an Exception that say I'm out of range of my stack. But it's not true, because if I try to go on previous page, I did it and I go on the NewPersonPage.
Why don't work correctly?

Comment: have you take a look to Navigation.NavigationStack.Count value before Navigation.RemovePage?

Comment: Yes. When remove page from NewPersonPage, the count is wright. But when I try to take a look the count in DetailsPage, the count is 0. Why? Is strange, because if it is really were 0, I could not back in the NewPersonPage...

Comment: you should post a repo on github so we can take a look.

Comment: I found the problem. Stack manipulation can not be done in the page builder because, for some reason, there the navigation stack count is equal to zero.